# Robot lawyer algorithm

Tags: reference-request, artificial-intelligence

I have a background in physics and have taken some few classes online in Machine learning. But I really do not understand how this Robot lawyer  can work:

[A 19-year-old made a free robot lawyer that has appealed $3 million in parking tickets](http://www.techinsider.io/joshua-browder-bot-for-parking-tickets-2016-2)

I am very interested in this type of artificial intelligence but I have no idea what to start reading about the topic.

Have somebody any idea of what type of algorithm he is using?

Here is what the article says:

> Browder programmed his robot based on a conversation algorithm. It uses keywords, pronouns, and word order to understand the user's issue. He says that the more people use the robot, the more intelligent it becomes. Its algorithm can quickly analyze large amounts of data while improving itself in the process.

Can the same algorithm also make the answer based on law data?

Comment: Mod comment: We have no way of knowing what that person used; all that remains is guesswork. You should rephrase your question to be clearly about references to techniques that would enable such a system -- which is likely every AI textbook ever written. (But you can't know that.)

Comment: I'll leave answering to experts, but it seems to me that the bot uses yes-no question, the answers to which are particularly easy to parse (no AI involved at all). The algorithm is then a simple [decision tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). Calling that AI is ... hyperbolic. If he had an algorithm that would work through law texts and case reports in a semi-automatic process and *build* such a bot, *that* would be a work of AI.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. My problem is that I do not know enough about the field to even ask a decent question.

Comment: Don't despair. I think "What the heck is he doing? How is that even possible?" is a good question to ask. It's just too broad for this platform (community votes are coming in). I have no idea if there are AI books or articles approachable to laypeople, but I guess you should start there. You say you have background in physics, so I think you should have the mathematical maturity to approach any introductory undergrad textbook on AI. Good luck!

Comment: Okay. But just to learn. Should I delete the question and find a better place to ask it?

Comment: Leave it be and let the community decide. I don't think it would be particularly suited for an SE site, but I suspect you would get many well-intentioned if not completely accurate answers on more practically inclined sites than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll join your potential downvote-fest with a speculation-filled answer.

Here are two Expert System algorithms I've worked with in industry.

**Rete Algorithm:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm

IBM and Oracle both have large Rete systems.

From what I've experienced, these are rules and fact tables that can be exeucted as a single atomic rule, or a million rules all on the same problem.  In my case we expressed these rules as tables of values, and IF/ELSE logic rules that can be grouped and managed and revised and controlled.

**General Problem Solver**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Problem_Solver

My impression is GPS is more flexible, and better handles the "fuzzy logic" cases and "precedence rules" (Where the answer changes when you reoder the precedence of the rules).

From my experience, I expressed these rules as small LISP functions where the tool could chose the "best" answer even if there still were unsolved values in the LISP functions.

**If I'm allowed to just blindly guess:**

My guess just from my gut feel, is that he's using Jess:

http://www.jessrules.com/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No I have some place to start reading:)

Comment: @fossekall On SE, you show your appreciation by upvoting useful answers, and accepting the one that helped you most.